# How can a ipv4-only network be serving ipv6?

Tags: networking, router, ipv6, teredo

My ISP's router only provides me with ipv4. However, a few days ago, I noticed that I could actually access a ipv6 address through my browser.

A few minutes ago I tried to install a package in apt in Ubuntu on Windows' WSL, and I was getting very slow speeds. After restarting the download I noticed that it was actually fetching packages from a ipv6 address.

After I disabled ipv6 support in my ethernet adapter I started getting normal speeds again.

I thought you couldn't access ipv6 addresses in a ipv4-only network. In the first time I tried to access that ipv6 website, I checked ipv6-test.com and it told me my network didn't support ipv6, but it supported DNS6+IP4. Right now I did a new test, and it says it's supported through teredo.

What could be happening? Could it be that my ISP just started rolling ipv6 to their costumers? Why would the internet connection be so slow when using ipv6 in these circumstances?

Comment: Does your ISP provide static IP for both IPv4 and IPv6? Does changing the DNS server work?

Comment: @Biswa As I said in the beginning of the question, only IPv4. What do you mean by "work"? I haven't tried to change the DNS server.

Comment: Change DNS to 8.8.8.8 (Google) or 208.67.222.222 (OpenDNS) and check the speed.

Answer (score 0):

From the Wikipedia article on [Teredo tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling):

> In computer networking, Teredo is a transition technology that gives
>   full IPv6 connectivity for IPv6-capable hosts that are on the IPv4
>   Internet but have no native connection to an IPv6 network. Unlike
>   similar protocols, it can perform its function even from behind
>   network address translation (NAT) devices such as home routers.
>
> Teredo operates using a platform independent tunneling protocol that
>   provides IPv6 (Internet Protocol version 6) connectivity by
>   encapsulating IPv6 datagram packets within IPv4 User Datagram Protocol
>   (UDP) packets. ...